# Git squash commits after pulling other commits from master branch

Tags: git, git-squash

Suppose I have the following commits on my local branch A, which I then push to the remote branch.

```
commit 1
commit 2
commit 3
commit 4
```

Now, I pull from the remote master, and the commit history looks like this -

```
//From branch A
commit 1
commit 2
commit 3
commit 4
//From master
commit 5
commit 6
```

If I now want to squash commits 2 and 3 using git rebase -i and git push -f, will that rewrite commits 5 and 6 as well? If yes, is there a way I can squash my earlier commits without rewriting the commits I pulled from the master branch? I'm new to Git, so please excuse me if I'm missing something very basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rebase won't rewrite those commits if you are in the feature branch and rebasing onto master. If your rebase range happened to run over commits 5 and 6, then they would get copied and modified, but you wouldn't lose anything. This is a normal operation, git doesn't change commits in-place, new ones get created with any required changes. Running `git rebase -i master` while inside your feature branch will copy the unique commits of your feature branch, and then re-apply them on an updated version of your branch.

Assuming commit 6 is your HEAD, commits 5 and 6 are essentially removed and reappear previous to commit 1 when the base of your branch is updated. Then commits 1-4 are replayed according to your instructions.

If, however, commit 1 was your HEAD, `git rebase -i master` will undo commits 1-4, and replay them with your squash instruction, resulting in a new history: 6 <- 5 <- 4 <- 1', where commits 2 and three have been squashed, and 5 and 6 are unaffected.

More details and better explanation on rebasing can be found [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing).

Comment: That worked, thank you! In the 2nd part of your answer, I'm assuming you meant "if, however, commit 4 was your HEAD,..." (that is, commits 5 and 6 were not yet pulled from master)?

Comment: It could be. I assumed you were starting at your second example, after "Now, I pull from the remote master". The beautiful part is that the solution works the same either way :).

Answer (score 0):

If you do what you suggest then **content** of commits `5` and `6` will remain unchanged (if there will be no rebase conflict), however their hash will be different, because their parents will change. So it won't be commits `5` and `6` anymore, but different one with the same content. Force pushing is ok, when you are sure nobody else is using that remote branch, otherwise you rewrite something he/she already pulled from the `remote`. I personally wouldn't do it on `remote/master`.